# C# Form1.cs file in the solution explorer - VS 2017

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I just switched to VS 2017 and in a Windows Form application, when I double click on the Form1 control, I'm of course directly directed to the Form1.cs code, where the loaded event is created. But I can not find this Form1.cs code file in the solution explorer. Where is it ?

**2015**
[image]

**2017**
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? This functionality hasn't changed in 2017 and I can see the form in my project.

Comment: I added a screenshot @john.

Comment: Is there any error when you build the solution?

Comment: No, everything went well @hiule.

Comment: Form1.cs  _is_ the code for the user-defined stuff. Form1.Designer.cs is the auto-generated UI code. If you want to access your code, just right-click Form1.cs and select "View code". --- To clarify: The UI you see is contained within Form1.Designer.cs, which is a partial class of Form1.cs. Form1.cs is your code.

Comment: While form.cs opened, Can you try to click Sync With active document button in the solution explorer ? It shows you the place of the file in the solution explorer

Comment: Sync With Active Document just highlights `Form1.cs [Design]*` in my case... @BurakAltin

Comment: I have Edited the question @john.

Comment: That's the _Class View_ - afaik you should only see that if you declare a nested class within your Form1 class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer, the "Form1.cs" file does double-duty: it represents both the Designer view of your form, and the C# code editor view. If you double-click it, the Designer comes up. But if you select it and press <kbd>F7</kbd>, you'll get the C# code. Likewise, if you right-click it and choose "View Code" from the menu. Or, you can select it and choose "Code" from the "View" menu.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2013 you see the Form1 class code icon and in VS2017 or later you don't. I'm not sure about VS2015. The behavior seems to have changed for no apparent reason other than to confuse lots of people (an internet search shows many questions and complaints about this).